# Wifi on Nano v3.0 ATmega328P-20AU Board

Tags: arduino, atmega

I am seeking a nano version of raspberry pi. For my application, I just need 2 two usb ports, 1 for a wifi module and the second to power the board via a 5v usb. I dont need the hdmi inputs in the pi. I want to be able to ssh into the board and run a python program.

I am considering the ATmega328P board. But I need to be abe to run queries on a mssql database and have python installed.

I may need an extra sd card module.

Any thoughts on the suitability of the nano 3.0 ATmega328P-20AU board ?

Answer (score 2):

The described requirement seems to fit the [BeagleBone Black](http://beagleboard.org/Products/BeagleBone+Black):

[image: BeagleBone Black]

The board is small (86.36 x 54.61 mm) though not as small as the Arduino Nano.

It has **2 USB** ports, one of which is USB **Host Mode**, which will be essential for the WiFi dongle. The second USB port can be used to power the board.

The BBB natively runs **Angstrom Linux**, and also supports BBB-specific Ubuntu and Android builds. Users can SSH into linux running on the BBB.

Several tutorials on using **Python on the BBB** are available, such as [this one for IO Python](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-io-python-library-on-beaglebone-black/overview).

In addition, WiFi "capes" (add-on boards) such as the [WL18xx](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Using_the_WL18xx_Cape_with_BeagleBone_Black) are available for the BBB. This may be a better-integrated option than using a WiFi dongle, courtesy the native support built into the BBB Angstrom Linux distribution.

The BBB offers the best of both worlds: High level use via Linux running on the main processor, as well as extensive low level functionality including GPIOs and timers based on the two 32-bit low-level PRU microcontrollers on the board. This provides several advantages over the Raspberry Pi, which somewhat restricts low-level hardware access.

The BBB board does have an HDMI port and a graphics accelerator on board, as well as a floating point accelerator, but those may be ignored if not needed.

Comment: I thought about BBB.  But for my vending machine project price is a big factor.  Bbb costs $55.  Want something cheaper than $25.

Comment: raspberry pi model a would still be a better choice then a BBB, it only costs $25.

Answer (score 1):

The RaspberryPi is a full blown linux computer. The Arduino Nano is a microcontroller dev board. They are not in the same league. Think Real car vs Radio Controlled Car. Yacht vs Row Boat.

While you can have Wifi on the Arduino, it involves very low level coding. TCP/IP stack, individual application support, etc. Same goes for trying to query a MySql database. And Python? It hasn't been successfully ported to the ATMega based Arduinos.

Price and Physical size wise, the RPi is better than the Nano.

Comment: I rather just try and use a microcontroller vs a CPU. Are there microcontroller boards that come with TCP/IP stack anddb support?

Comment: I can just use C/C++ no need for python porting.

Comment: The BCM2835 is a SoC, not an MCU.