# Wifi on ATmega328P-AU

Tags: atmega, wifi

This is in continuation to my earlier post here:

[Wifi on Nano v3.0 ATmega328P-20AU Board](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/116528/wifi-on-nano-v3-0-atmega328p-20au-board)

What if I got a USB hub and connected a wifi USB dongle. Will that provide wifi functionality?

Comment: You are probably better off with a module like for example [WiFly](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10822) as the required drivers for these modules are far more 'embedded system friendly'.

Comment: I think with that price tag of $34 I might as well buy a raspberry pi model b for $39 and get wifi+sd+cpu. A mcu would only make sense if it offered wifi under $20. But good post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ATmega328P on its own has neither USB host nor USB OTG capability. Connecting a USB device to it will have no effect. Either get a SPI Wi-Fi module such as something based on the [CC3000](http://www.ti.com/product/cc3000) instead, or select a MCU with OTG capability such as the [AT90USB1287](http://www.atmel.com/devices/at90usb1287.aspx).

Comment: your correct. But I can't find a development board with that MCU.

Comment: http://store.atmel.com/PartDetail.aspx?q=p:10500313#tc:description

Comment: Remember you need, apart from USB hardware support, some drivers if you connect a module through USB. WiFi device drivers under Linux are already often dramatic, let alone if you need to write your own on an embedded platform. If you want to travel the USB road, be very sure you have all the required drivers (sources) available.